# Total Change vs Average Total Change

Tags: average, percentages

Someone help me get a grasp of this. Feel like am missing some math principles:

If I have

```
     2018 2019
      1     2
      3     4
      5     6
      7     8
Total 16    20
```

The percentage change in totals for $2019$ is $\left[\dfrac{20}{16}-1\right]$% $= 25$%

Shouldn't this give the same result as calculating the individual change for each row and averaging the sum of these?

That is: $\dfrac{(100 + 33.3 + 20 + 14.3)}4 ?$

Comment: @The Demonix _ Hermit it's MathJaX not $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 0):

No. What is equivalent is if you express each change in terms of the average of the 2018 values. ${1+3+5+7\over 4}={16\over 4}$ So the change is $25\%+25\%+25\%+25\%= 100\%$ of their average. which when averaged is $25\%$

Comment: This does not answer why the two are different. I don't understand. Why is total change different than average change.